# Flutter native widget + XPay by Nexi

Tags: swift, flutter, dart

Hello I've a Flutter App.

I need to use the native IOS View (CardFormMulti) of XPaySDK:
https://ecommerce.nexi.it/specifiche-tecniche/sdkperapp/ios.html

The problem is that the screen stay white.

Flutter code:

```
SizedBox(
   width: 300,
   height: 300,
   child: UiKitView(viewType: 'xpaynexi'),
)
```

The important Swift code (I've omitted the factory's class):

```
public class XpayNexiView : NSObject, FlutterPlatformView {
    var frame: CGRect
    let viewId: Int64
    var finalView: UIStackView

    init(_ frame: CGRect, viewId: Int64, args :Any?) {
        self.frame = frame
        self.viewId = viewId
     }

     public func view() -> UIView {
         return XPaySDK.CardFormMulti(frame: frame)
     }
```

If in the func view() of swift code I return in the a UISlider, for example, I can correctly see the slider in the flutter app.

Someone can help me? Thanks

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?